# PEAR::Mail 'failed to add recipient'

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

Here's the failing code:

```php
require_once "Mail.php";

$host           = "mail.domain.com";
$username       = "USER";
$password       = "PASS";

$mailto     = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';
$subject        = 'My Subject';
$from           = 'Client Name <info@clientdomain.com>';

$headers = array (
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $mailto,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array (
        'host' => $host,
        'port' => '25',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    )
);

$mail = $smtp->send($mailto, $headers, $msg);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {    
    echo '<br /><br />' . $mail->getMessage();
} else {
    echo '<br /><br />Worked';
}
```

I am passing the $email value to the script as follows:

```php
$name = 'Joe Schmoe';
$email = 'webmaster@domain.com';
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/my/code/above.php');
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
Failed to add recipient: webmaster@domain.com@localhost
[SMTP: Invalid response code received from server
(code: 504, response: 5.5.2 :
    Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address)]
```

If I change the $mailto variable from:

```
$mailto     = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';
```

... to the following:

```
$mailto     = $name . ' <webmaster@domain.com>';
```

It works perfectly.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: What is the value of your $email variable?

Comment: try printing out the contents of `$email` looks like somehow `@localhost` is added to your `webmaster@domain.com` string

Comment: ADRIEN: $email is dynamically loaded before the include. Specific to this example, 'webmaster@domain.com' (sans-quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `@localhost` is added to your `$email` variable in `Mail.php`

Try changing the name of the `$email` variable in your script.

Also you can use `die($email);` in your script to test the value of email in various stages.

Comment: Yes, I see that @localhost is being added - but only when I load $mailto with the $email variable. I am loading $email with 'webmaster@domain.com' (sans-quotes) and I can output $email (from the script) with no errors. Could this be an string encoding issue?

Comment: UPDATE: No difference when I changed the name of the variable. $email is passing the address "correctly" (hehe). What I don't get is why it would append the email address with @localhost when loaded via a variable; then not append (and work correctly) when the value is hard coded.

Comment: just for testing you could put `die($email);` after this line: `$mailto     = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';`
Also `require_once "Mail.php";` is included after `$email` is defined so thats probably the place where `@localhost` is added.

Comment: Got it! Your die() placement suggestion revealed that it was not the php script after all. It was 'when' $email was being loaded. I didn't test the value early enough in the script to see any differences.